# Threads are getting blocked on weblogic clustered environment

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

I have a weblogic clustered environment with 2 instances of servers. One of which is getting hanged and other one is working perfectly fine. After analysing the thread dumps I can see that almost 90% of the threads are BLOCKED and after tracing the threads it comes to below stack trace.

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '330' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f9494376000 nid=0x66a2 runnable [0x00007f944bb78000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1080)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:199)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
```

Please find below the thread dump for the `BLOCKED` thread.

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '298' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f9494352000 nid=0x6276 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f944e09e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000719e7ded8> (a weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.loadClass(PackagingDataCalculator.java:207)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.bestEffortLoadClass(PackagingDataCalculator.java:232)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.computeBySTEP(PackagingDataCalculator.java:138)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.populateUncommonFrames(PackagingDataCalculator.java:113)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.populateFrames(PackagingDataCalculator.java:105)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.PackagingDataCalculator.calculate(PackagingDataCalculator.java:57)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.calculatePackagingData(ThrowableProxy.java:147)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent. (LoggingEvent.java:124)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:440)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:396)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.warn(Logger.java:713)
```

This stack trace is similar for all other `BLOCKED` threads as well.

Please let me know if anyone has come across such issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is a dump of a thread in the `RUNNABLE` state. This thread is not blocked, it's running and doing some work (it's checking a Java library existence, to be exact). You need to find a `BLOCKED` thread and make its dump, it will be a better way to start the analysis of your problem.

Comment: Yes. This is a RUNNABLE thread, but all the BLOCKED threads are tracing back to this RUNNABLE thread as I mentioned in the description. All the BLOCKED threads are waiting to get lock on the monitor of this thread.

Comment: That's strange. Usually, if a thread holds a lock, you can see it in its thread dump (it has a "locked ..." line). It might occur that all your threads need to load the same Java class, but the class loader has stuck on the library loading in this thread. Could you post a thread dump of one of the blocked threads? If you make dumps of this running thread with a 10-second interval, do all these dumps have the same stack trace?

Comment: I have updated the information on BLOCKED threads in the question

Comment: It looks like my guess about a blocked class loader was right. Logback is trying to log a message but needs some class that hasn't been loaded yet. But it cannot load this class because one of the loaders down the class loaders hierarchy is stuck trying to load some library (maybe the same as Logback needs, maybe another). Does it happen on Linux? Do you have dependencies on mounted disks that you reach through network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread dumps indicate that your threads are blocked while trying to write log messages. Logback needs some class and asks a class loader to load it. Somewhere down the class loaders hierarchy, one of the class loaders is stuck while loading a library and it causes all other threads to hang waiting for this loader.

Most likely, you have a dependency library that is placed on a mounted network disk that is either unreachable or extremely slow or has some bad blocks. It causes the hang on reading this library. Check your classpath, check disks and the network.